# Sexual parasite centaur?

Tags: aliens, anatomy, lifecycle

I have this idea for an alien centaur species which goes through an aquatic juvenile stage looking vaguely like this: [image]

Then the males attach themselves to the females and they're able to leave the water looking like this:
[image]

My question is how plausible is this biology? I don't know exactly where their genitals are but they would be roughly where ours are. Can you see some crucial flaw in this idea that makes it all fall apart? I apologize for the crudity of the drawings. This idea is still vague.

Comment: Why do you call it a parasite?

Comment: Answerers: note the two little eyes in the adult phase. The back half (the "body") appears to be the male which is fully supporting the female in front. This is something like an angler fish situation but without the male becoming a pair of testicles after fusion.

Comment: I thought parasite was the right term. Am I wrong?

Comment: A parasite in a relationship actively takes from or harms the parasitized species /individual without giving any benefit in return. Even a child perpetuates your genes. This looks a lot more cooperative. At the very least, the male is contributing essential DNA to the reproductive process needed for species survival.

Comment: If anything, this reminds me a lot of angler fish, except that the relationship is much more one-sided and the male essentially devolves into a pair of testicles. Maybe reading a bit on that might help you flesh out your concept a bit?

Comment: I know about that. I was just hoping to reflect the idea of some people

Comment: VTC because I consider it absolutely impossible to objectively address the plausibility of a fictional creature (even with imagination) based entirely on two sketches. The [help/on-topic] requires questions to be specific and we love helping people design creatures. Asking if your creature is plausible in the Real World *before* you've designed it is pretty much a "no." So let's design it first. What's your specific question? (Ambiguous "I've got this crazy idea" questions are great for [chat], but inappropriate for Main.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## [Symbiosis / Obligate Mutualism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbiosis)!

At least, that is what the biologists in the room would call this. I am assuming fusion is permanent, and separation is deadly for the critters involved. Otherwise it's not "obligate," just Symbiosis/mutualism.

It seems like the two creatures need some excellent coordination to move effectively on land. This will require some very fast mechanism to communicate "go there." This is possible through chemical communication or even through touch.

## [IRL: Kinda Like Anglerfish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anglerfish) and [Dragonflies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragonfly)

Anglerfish do something like this. The males must seek out females and then "fuse" with them, being a parasite until they're just a pair of gonads that release sperm to mate.

The difference here is that both creatures work together as if a larger creature. This is kinda like dragonflies flying in tandem. These dragonflies are a male/female pair, and it is not uncommon for mates (in the animal kingdom) to stick around each other or even "hitch rides." This frequently serves to prevent other males from mating with the female.

It's the combination of these two things that make this really unique! I am going to say this is *possible*, but perhaps not *plausible*. Some life cycles can get really complicated, like many parasites do, so absurd or unlikely lifecycles shouldn't be immediately ruled out.

However, consider that this kind of fusion has happened in one group of creatures from *all the animal kingdom.* Even then, not all anglerfish have developed this strategy! Guarding your mate by hitching a ride is, in comparison, more common. Once again, this is something that *could* happen: no physical laws are preventing from this happening. Assuming the communication issue is solved between the two organisms, there is no reason why this should not work.