# Symbiosis centaur male?

Tags: aliens, anatomy

My previous question [Sexual parasite centaur?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/232594/sexual-parasite-centaur/232600#232600) was about a symbiotic relationship where the males and females of the species are conjoined in such a way that they form a centaur shape. They start in an aquatic juvenile stage and then conjoin like anglerfish but the female is smaller. But the problem is I have no idea what to do with the head of the male. The female I want to basically be human due to an alien seeding experiment. What would the male head even have to look like given it's fate? Here's the basic sketch of the adult.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a survival advantage the males head could give the symbiont eyes on their back, allowing them to see what is behind them.

The males head being sunken into the females body would be the most aesthetically pleasing design but for this survival edge, the males neck and tip of the chin can rest on the females back, their head fully tilted backwards allows them to see behind them, although their view is upside down they will adjust to this. The males head from this position can sink into the females back allowing his spinal column to merge with hers, linking up nerves to become one sensory system. How much of his head is visible is up to you, it could just be a strange pair of eyes on her back, or the mouth also if you want a secondary respiratory system.

Answer (score 3):

If they become symbiotic and there is no use for a spare head, it can simply wither and become atrophic: it's a waste of resources having something that does nothing, the same way as one legs and arms get thinner and slimmer if they sit all day at a desk instead of lifting weights.

If there is already a head which ensures breathing/eating/communicating, there is no need for an additional one. The brain, if still needed, can simply relocate inside the body and the head can get atrophic.

Answer (score 3):

It can burrow into the spine of the female, giving it access to the female's central nervous system and allowing it to partially control or intimately interact with the host, or even merge their consciousness.
This way, communication about its mobile and other functioning is near-instantaneous, and their synergy is perfect.

The male secretes a substance from glands inside its mouth with anti-bacterial and anaesthetic properties, which allows for a rapid recovery of the wound he necessarily has to inflict.
Due to oxygenation, this secretion covers the wound in mere minutes, allowing it to heal undisturbedly.